# Slow Booting Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 & facing the problem that it is taking much time to boot, so I installed bootchart to see which process is taking much time but could not understand the chart .png image file, so here I am attaching the bootchart image file : 
[image]

I am using ubuntu only (no dual boot) & my hardware config is : 
`Memory 4GB`,

`Processor Intel core i3-3110M 4 CPU @ 2.40GHZ`

`Graphics Intel Ivybridge Mobile`

`Os type 64-bit`

`SSD 500 GB`

can anybody instruct me how to analyse the bootchart & disable the unnecessary processes which is responsible for slow booting.

Comment: what is your hardware config and have you dual booted your machine

Comment: I am running Ubuntu only & my hardware config is : Memory 4GB, Processor Intel core i3-3110M 4 CPU @ 2.40GHZ, Graphics Intel Ivybridge Mobile, Os type 64-bit,Disk 500 GB

Comment: Have you tried disabling ureadahead?

Comment: how do i do that? pl help.

Comment: `mv /etc/init/ureadahead.conf{,.bak}` (use `mv /etc/init/ureadahead.conf{.bak,}` to restore it after testing)

Comment: what does this process do. pl explain